# How to show date every month in plotly?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I want to show the date for every 1 month, but it shows every 2 months instead. I also wonder how to tilt the date (x axis) 60 degree in plotly. Is these two things possible in plotly? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
l <- list(
  font = list(
    family = "sans-serif",
    size = 12,
    color = "#364E6F"),
  bgcolor = "#E4EBF5",
  bordercolor = "#566F92",
  borderwidth = 3)


fig <- plot_ly(sumir_data, x = sumir_data$`Month-year`, y = sumir_data$`Followers-LI`, type = 'bar', name = 'LinkedIn', marker = list(color = '#28EDC4'))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = sumir_data$`EOM Followers Twitter-TW`, name = 'Twitter', marker = list(color = '#00BBFF'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Followers Count',
                                         color = '#364E6F'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Date',
                                         color = '#364E6F'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(legend = l)
fig <- fig %>% layout(paper_bgcolor = '#E4EBF5',
                                              plot_bgcolor = '#E4EBF5')

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide sample data or use a public dataset that has month/year as a usable field?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to add dticks = "M1" to the xaxis layout()

My code:

```
l <- list(
  font = list(
    family = "sans-serif",
    size = 12,
    color = "#364E6F"),
  bgcolor = "#FFFFFF",
  bordercolor = "#566F92",
  borderwidth = 3)


fig <- plot_ly(sumir_data, x = sumir_data$`Month-year`, y = sumir_data$`Followers-LI`, type = 'bar', name = 'LinkedIn', marker = list(color = '#28EDC4'))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = sumir_data$`EOM Followers Twitter-TW`, name = 'Twitter', marker = list(color = '#00BBFF'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Number of Followers',
                                         color = '#364E6F'))

fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Date',
                                         color = '#364E6F', dtick = "M1"))
fig <- fig %>% layout(legend = l)
fig <- fig %>% layout(paper_bgcolor = '#FFFFFF',
                                              plot_bgcolor = '#FFFFFF')

fig
```

[image]